# Regarding a Specific C Variable

Tags: c

It is a simple question, what does this set SrcPkt to?

```
extern PacketStruct RxPacket[NUM_PACKETS], TxPacket[NUM_PACKETS];
extern IPMBPacketRequestStruc *SrcPkt;


SrcPkt = (IPMBPacketRequestStruc *)&(RxPacket[i].packetdata[0]);
```

I have a solid understanding of C and C++ but pointers have always been my weak point.
This line of code seems to set the pointer SrcPkt to point to the reference of RxPacket[i].packetdata[0]

I am only partly confident with what I believe is the correct answer, I just want some validation.
EDIT:

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char status;   // Buffer status
  unsigned char stat2;    // re-send status
  unsigned char channel;    // Channel source/destination
  unsigned char length; // Total # of bytes in packetdata
  unsigned char index;  // Current byte being processed in packetdata
  unsigned char packetdata[IPMB_MAXDATALENGTH];
} PacketStruct;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char rsSA;
    unsigned char netFNrsLUN;
    unsigned char cksm1;
    unsigned char rqSA;
    unsigned char rqSEQrqLUN;
    unsigned char cmd;
    unsigned char pktdta[37];   // rest of packet data
} IPMBPacketRequestStruc;
```

Comment: BTW you could compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** `gdb` to run your program step by step and query the program's state (notably value of pointer variable). You'll improve your understanding. Try hard to draw a picture of memory (with arrow for pointers) on paper.

Comment: BTW, your question lacks some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without more code (definition of types : what *eactly* is `PacketStruct` etc...) we can only guess, not answer. And drawing on board the pointers is really my best advice. Please take time to try (and run `step` by step under `gdb`)

Comment: You have 2 arrays of some structure type and a pointer to another, which are all defined in another source. Then you assign to SrcPkt a pointer, derivered from casting the address of the first element of some member of the i-th element of the RxPacket array. At least to my understanding.

Comment: @Josh, don't call anybody like this, here. Basile is correct, it does affect the rest of your C knowledge. For your question, it seems pretty obvious that this takes the `i`th element, there the field `packetdata` and of that one the element `0`. Then it takes the address of all that. What in that chain didn't you understand?

Comment: We can't help you. We don't know (only vaguely guess) what `PacketStruct`is... Perhaps (but unlikely) you have `typedef char PacketStruct;` We need some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Josh you provide 2 lines of code, which contains some structure types and we have no description for them. In my comment I explained what the lines of code do, but this is all (at least I) can do.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thank you for the clarification, which is what was specified in the question. I will work on pointers to complete my understanding, for now I was simply asking a question to verify something for the time being.

Comment: @Josh: **We cannot answer your question** because *essential information is missing:* what is`IPMBPacketRequestStruc`? what is `PacketStruct` ? We don't know, we could just guess, and our guess would be wrong. `packetdata` could be some complex macro, etc...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Added the (actually likely) typedef.

Comment: Too bad you did not send me any email....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Explained it in previous comments. Why did you want me to email you so badly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets `SrcPkt` to point to the *address* of RxPacket[i].packetdata[0]. The `&` operator returns the address of (a pointer to) the packet data, which is cast to the same type as `SrcPkt` and assigned to the `SrcPkt` pointer variable.

*References*, as exist in C++, do not exist in C. In C++, they are usually implemented as syntactic sugar around pointers so that you can use the objects they point to without having to manually dereference them. In C, you must handle and dereference pointers yourself.